Are the hangers on these joists sized and installed properly?
The hangers on these joists seem too small, and some of the nails are right near the bottom edge of the supporting ledger. Are they ok?


Note: This question was prompted by discussion on another post. I have no further details to provide.

I guess the answer would be: only a structural engineering report can answer this. You have such issues to consider as the span and dimensions of joists, the required load to be carried, the carrying capacity of the beam, the type of nails, and the actual strength of the hanger itself. One of these factors is bound to be weaker than the others, but it can just be no worse than what's specified. That's the most precise answer to the question.
My perspective is that with every craftsman a devotee to Belt and Suspenders®, if the joists are 2 by 10, those hangers need to be 2 by 10 hangers. A 2 by 10 hanger has 10 nail holes on the beam side to carry load from the joist to the beam. A 10d nail is rated to carry 75 lbs for a total load transfer of 750 lbs per joist. Obviously, the scenario in the picture can't use this because the I-beam is probably fitted with 2 by 6 or another lumber, but Simpson has a wide range of hangers for each intended application. One should plan the depth and number of nails to achieve at least 750 lbs, but at the end of the day, the engineering report has all the details.
Another minor quibble is that I have doubts about nails in the direction of failure. The lower nail is toenailed into the hanger, angled at nearly 45 degrees since it would obviously split the wood otherwise. Minor deflection in the beam or joist will pull this nail loose with time. You get optimal structure by nailing flush with the hanger. Again the hanger product has directions on this.

I'm the OP OP, thanks for this comment.
I consulted a structural engineer who did just what you described with me. He gave me an exact recipe for how to lift up and modify this steel beam, what hangers to use, what bolts to put through the beam, a tertiary post in the basement to help with load, and much more.
To address the bulk of your answer: I am using the proper joist hangers for this size of joist. They're 2x8s and I'm using Simpson Strong Tie LU26, which according to them, is for 2x8s.

to address your minor quibble, I drilled new holes in the few hangers that had questionable nails and drove new nails through. I realize this compromises the structural integrity of the hanger but I estimated it to be a net positive overall.

@KoreyKostek LU26 hangars can be used for 2x8s this is true. if all the nails are used.  you are missing a 1/4 of your nails (effectively). I know that the LU28 hangars cost 20 cents more per hangar and requires 4 more nails to install. Which probably makes it 40.45 cents more expensive per hanger. But I think pinching pennies when doing construction on a place you plan to live in is stupid.

@KoreyKostek Not being a structural engineer, it looks like in your original photo the hanger would only support ~50% of the designed load (2 out of 4 nails), so I'm glad you shored it up!  Maybe you could post an "after" photo to get comments on that. I don't think your structural engineer took into account the difference in depth of the two boards, which is causing the bottom nail to be so close to the edge of the supporting board.

if the joists are 2 by 10... then their ledger is to be also, if not larger. because, that's what fits in the I-beam doesn't count. It's the right hanger for a 2x6 ledger. It's the wrong size ledger tho : "I actually did consider using the "taller" Simpson hanger for 2x10s, but I found that the lowest nail was in the same position anyway, and the taller nail spot would have been too high to make contact with the wood."

There's a part number stamped on the bottom. look that up and read the instructions, it will cover the suitability of that hanger.
I suspect that taller hangers should have been used here, or the joists should have been notched as there is very little wood below the lower nail to the beam
If you want professional help try a building inspector, I'm expecting a "That aint right" for this work.

Should be noted that there’s a broad range of aptitudes in under the building inspector umbrella. I’m biased, but I’d be getting an engineer or a GC with an engineer on speed dial. (And while I’m pretty sure the engineer would also say, ‘that ain’t right’, they could proscribe a fix for that narrow issue and consider whether other fixes might need to happen.

@AloysiusDefenestrate there's a certain Texas Youtuber with that catch phrase who's famous for checking hangers, and sill plate anchor bolt - but note he's a private home inspector, not a municipal.

What I have seen allows that 2X4 hangers will work for 2X6s, 2X6 hangers will work for 2X8s and 2x8 hangers will work for 2X10s. This is according to the manufacturer of the hangers. These appear to be 2X6 hangers on a 2X10.
These hangers, in this situation are not sufficient.

Those appear to be Simpson Strongtie face mount hangers.  I can't be sure because I can't read the stamp clearly.  And they appear to be LUS26 hangers holding 2x10 joists.  Again, a guess because there are no measurements provided.
Sawn lumber connection manufacturers publish complete specs for the components they make and sell.  For example, Simpson Strontie produces, among dozens or hundreds of other documents, a matrix that summarizes the specs for their face mount hangers:  https://ssttoolbox.widen.net/view/pdf/giyt98mijo/C-C-2024_p108-112.pdf?t.download=true
So, if this is a Simpson Strongtie LUS26 holding a 2x10, that's the wrong hanger.
Also of concern is that the board that is bolted to the steel beam appears by be a 1x.  These hangers require a 3" fastener into the header.  0.75" is insufficient.  I'm guessing from the picture that those are 1.5" 10d TCo's holding the connector.  I can't tell if they were cut to 0.75" or if they were driven into the steel.  The connection manufacturer probably provides information regarding fastening the connectors directly to the steel beam either by welding or using an appropriate metal screw.  And it's likely possible to fur out the connection by using a piece of 1x lumber, as long as the appropriate faster is used.

And there is no washer under the bolt head holding the wood to the steel beam.

Looks to me like doubled up 2x6s. Fur it out... with a 2x10 and use the right hangers that didn't seem to work because it's not the right size ledger.

I read the picture as thicker wood inside the coves of a rolled steel joist (I section beam), if it is thin wood on a rectangular hollow steel beam then  you can nail into the steel with explosive powered nails, or screw with self drilling screws.
